# Hiding the action bar

Tags: android, xml

It is a sample on the book.
I'm trying to hide the action bar by setting the theme to Theme.Holo.NoActionBar:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
    ... >
        ...
</activity>
```

However, when I tried this I get the following exception:

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

What does this mean? How can I get around this?

I'm new to android programming.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the java code of that activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this message is because you're using a compatibility library, or you've set your minimum SDK level too low. Basically the Holo theme didn't exist in the API version you're trying to maintain compatibility with.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBarActivity` requires a `Theme.AppCompat` theme as it assumes you want an Action Bar (hence its name). If you do not want an action bar, your activity should extend from [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) which contains everything but the Action Bar from `ActionBarActivity`. Then you can use `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar` without issue.